# Web-api security: SSL?

Tags: security, ssl, asp.net-web-api

I'd to know how to restrict web-api's requests to a specific client.

The web-api would be hosted on computer A.

The client (for now only one) - would be hosted on computer **B**.

Different servers, machines, etc.

How to make my web-api only "respond" to the client on computer **B**?
Using SSL?

1. How this works?
2. Do I need to treat anything on the server side?
3. We might need in the future a mobile app to use the same web-api. In this case, how can I "allow" my app's requests to be answered by web-api?
4. If SSL solves the problem, I must only install the certificates on server and client?

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options and they depend more or less on the environment where your machines work. In general I'd look into three mechanisms:

1. Client certificate authentication (also known as *mutual authentication* or *2-way TLS*). This basically means that both machines present a certificate to each other for verification. This approach is quite common in server to server communication. It is generally quite a good and secure approach but the trade-off is that adding new trusted clients is a bit of extra hassle because you will need to issue certificates for it.
2. Whitelisting of IPs or hostnames (or entire subnets etc). In other words have a configuration on your server to restrict the pool of allowed clients by their origins. This approach doesn't include any cryptography and the client can easily spoof its origin but you can sometimes see this being used as an addition (extra layer) to other mechanisms.
3. API keys. Integrate or implement key-based authorization to use the API. This is commonly used to authorize mobile applications to use web APIs. One of the most common problems with API keys are their protection. You will need to find a way to make it reasonably difficult for anybody to steal those keys. Ultimately this is often impossible with mobile applications, but you always need to make the risk evaluation anyway and see what is reasonable mitigation for your found risks.

You can combine these mechanisms together to add additional layers. You can also set up firewalls and network restrictions for even more layers. But always take moment to evaluate the risks and the value of whatever you are trying to protect. Then you will know what is the reasonable cost and effort to use for the protection.

This is not a complete list of all possibilities out there, but I hope you find it a helpful set of pointers to get started.

Comment: I understand that combining these mechanisms is a good idea. As for white IP lists, I think we can make "fake" requests by modifying the customer's identity, can't we? And what about SSL? I don't have a clue about it... maybe i'm making confusion

Comment: Yes spoofing the IP is not rocket science so IP or host whitelists should be only used with other mechanisms. SSL, or TLS, is a crypto layer for the network communication. The point 1, basically describes how you can use it to authorize both parties. Note that the certificate issuers can be different between the two ends, but the issuer must be trusted by the receiver.